# jQuery triggering mutliple divs with same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm currently working with the Cycle 2 plugin, and here is the code I have at the moment :

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
$('.cycle-slideshow').hover(function () {
    //mouse enter - Resume the slideshow
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('resume');
},
function () {
    //mouse leave - Pause the slideshow
    $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
});
});
```

I'm generating some divs with the same class, as followed (with PHP) :

```
for ($i=0; $i < $sizearray; $i++) { 
    echo '<li><a target="_blank" href="...">
    <div class="cycle-slideshow"<center><img src="..."></div</center></a></li>';
}
```

My problem is that jQuery triggers all the elements with the same class at the same time, which is obvious, but I can't find a way to get jQuery to do it seperately for each div !

Any tip ? :D

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).cycle('resume')` to just do the one the mouse is over?

Comment: Got it ! Works like a charm ! Thanks mate ! :D

Answer (score 0):

So nnnnnn gave me the answer in the comments :

I just change the code to :

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('pause');
$('.cycle-slideshow').hover(function () {
    //mouse enter - Resume the slideshow
    $(this).cycle('resume')
},
function () {
    //mouse leave - Pause the slideshow
    $(this).cycle('pause')
});

});
```